# How do I use environment variables in an attribute name in jboss' standalone.xml?

Tags: docker, configuration, jboss, jboss7.x

I understand that within a field, I can pull an environment variable with the syntax of ${env.VARIABLE_NAME}, however, whenever I try to do so within an attribute name, jboss throws an error.

What I have done, and works

```
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/database" pool-name="database" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>${env.DS_CONNECTION_URL}</connection-url>
                    <driver>${env.DS_DRIVER}</driver>
                </datasource>
```

What I want to do, which is failing

```
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="${env.FORMATTER}"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
```

I have also tried starting without the surrounding quotes. I have created a child xml element with the value of name and the environment variable, but that has also failed.

I expect the environment variable FORMATTER to be used as the name, but instead I get the following error on attempting to start jboss.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Formatter "${env.FORMATTER}" is not found
```

Comment: It seems the `FORMATTER` environment variable is not passed correctly to the container. How do you run the container? This [How to pass variable as attribute to xml configuration file in Wildfly with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44760127/8482479) may help.

Comment: In my Dockerfile, I am running
```CMD source fileName.conf```
That file includes all of my envrionment variables, which I can see working in other parts of my application. The line is
```export FORMATTER=COLOR-PATTERN```

I would like to note that this works when I try to use an environment variable outside of an attribute name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions are not allowed for the `named-formatter` attribute. In most cases it doesn't make much sense as the formatter would have to be defined and cannot have a dynamic name.

If you look at the [model description](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/17.0/subsystem/logging/console-handler/index.html) documentation you can see which attributes support expressions.

Comment: Oh! That's it. Thank you for the link to the documentation!

I want this because I want my formatter to be format in nice colors in my development environment, but to be a formatter that my logging framework can interpret in our test and production environment. I'll keep poking around to see if there's a way to accomplish this. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be to use two different configuration files which is likely not idea. Feel free to file an enhancement here though https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE. It seem reasonable for the `named-formatter` to allow for expressions.

Answer (score 0):

How to pass env variables to the attributes of other formatter's properties?

```
<meta-data>
      <property name="ENV" value="${env.MY_ENVIRONMENT}"/>
</meta-data>
```

is not working when running

```
docker run -p 8081:9990 -p 8080:8080 -e MY_ENVIRONMENT="DEV" --name c1 c1img:1.1.2
```

I still see

```
..."ENV":"${env.MY_ENVIRONMENT}"...
```